# Simple way to clear the value of any input inside a div?

Tags: javascript, forms, dom

Is there a simple way to iterate over the child elements in an  element, say a div, and if they are *any* sort of input (radio, select, text, hidden...) clear their value?

**Edit** to add link to [example solution code.](http://www.nolaflash.com/stackoverflow/clearChildren.html)  Many thanks to Guffa and the other respondents!  I learned from this!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I suppose that you want to clear all children, not only the direct children, so it would have to be recursive. As different input elements is cleared differently, you have to check their type so that you know what to do with them. I suppose that you want to clear textareas also, but leave buttons unchanged:

```
function clearChildren(element) {
   for (var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++) {
      var e = element.childNodes[i];
      if (e.tagName) switch (e.tagName.toLowerCase()) {
         case 'input':
            switch (e.type) {
               case "radio":
               case "checkbox": e.checked = false; break;
               case "button":
               case "submit":
               case "image": break;
               default: e.value = ''; break;
            }
            break;
         case 'select': e.selectedIndex = 0; break;
         case 'textarea': e.innerHTML = ''; break;
         default: clearChildren(e);
      }
   }
}
```

Call it with a reference to the element:

```
clearChildren(document.getElementById('IdOfTheDiv'));
```

Edit:
Forgot the select...

Edit 2:
Some corrections: childNodes.length, handling elements without tagName and uppercase tagName values.

Comment: Good assumption about needing it to work on children's children, however you don't need recursion to grab descendant nodes.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!!  I am trying to implement this and have a strange symptom.  There is no visible effect on a simple test form.  If I get alert to print element I get [object HTMLDivElement] (good..) If I get alert() to print element.childNodes it has [object nodeLIst] (good again) but if I get alert() to echo the value of i inside the for() it never fires so it seems like it does not iterate over the nodes?  Code like:  function clearChildren(element) {
   for (var i = 0; i < element.childNodes; i++) {
      var e = element.childNodes[i];
     alert('i:'+i);

Comment: Changed for (var i = 0; i < element.childNodes; i++)  to for (var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++) and got iteration working.  Still not clearing values but working to see why now

Comment: ah, it needed to be  case 'INPUT': not  case 'input':

w00t!1  Working now, thanks!!!

Comment: @crescentfresh: Yes, you don't *need* recursion. Actually you never do, there is always a different way to solve it, but it works well with nested elements. :)

Comment: @jerrygarciuh: I made some corrections above, including handling elements that doesn't have a tagName at all (i.e. textnodes).

Answer (score 15):

Very simple with JQuery:

```
$('#myDiv').children().find('input,select').each(function(){
   $(this).val('');
});
```

We can put as many tags in the "find" call.

Comment: nice one...just wondering if you can do this without children()? for instance: $('#myDiv').find('input,select').each(function(){

$(this).val('');

});

Answer (score 7):

Oh boy, this would be a one liner with jQuery:

```
$(':input:not(:button)', div).val([])
```

Without jQuery you've got to account for `<select>` fields, text fields, password fields and radio/checkbox fields:

```
function clearFields(container) {
    var selects = container.getElementsByTagName('select');

    for(var i=0, len=selects.length; i < len; i++) {
        selects[i].selectedIndex = -1;
    }

    var fields = container.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for(var i=0, len=fields.length; i < len; i++) {
        var field = fields[i];
        switch(field.type)
        {
            case 'radio':
            case 'checkbox':
                field.checked = false;
                break;

            case 'text':
            case 'password':
            case 'hidden':
                field.value = ''
        }
    }

    var fields = container.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
    for(var i=0, len=fields.length; i < len; i++) {
        fields[i].value = ''
    }
}
```

Comment: The jQuery solution doesn't handle checkboxes or radio buttons, and it clears the text of buttons...

Answer (score 5):

Karim's answer works well. Using jQuery, I believe it'll go something like this:

```
$("#myDiv").each(function(){
   if($(this).type == "input")
      $(this).val('');
});
```

Actually, come to think of it, you may also try:

```
$("#myDiv input").val('');//myDiv is your Div name
```

Comment: I have some Scriptaculous effects alreay in this page.  Would it create conflicts to also load in jQuery?

Comment: you can use the following to avoid clashes: add jQuery.noConflict();
to the top of your page, and substitute every '$' with the word jQuery when calling a jQuery function. More here: http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Comment: Thanks TTG!  I will look into this now!1

Answer (score 2):

Kudos, Haresh! Small addition to uncheck checkboxes. (Use true to check all.)

```
$('#myDiv').children().find('input,select').each(function(){

$(this).val('');
$(this).attr('checked',false);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to clear all type of input form elements value

```
function clear_form_elements(id_name) {
  jQuery("#"+id_name).find(':input').each(function() {
    switch(this.type) {
        case 'password':
        case 'text':
        case 'textarea':
        case 'file':
        case 'select-one':       
            jQuery(this).val('');
            break;
        case 'checkbox':
        case 'radio':
            this.checked = false;
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post but someone can see it.

```
function clearFields(divElement) {
    var ancestor = document.getElementById(divElement),
    descendents = ancestor.getElementsByTagName('*');

    var i, e, d;
    for (i = 0; i < descendents.length; ++i) {
        if (descendents[i].tagName.toLowerCase() == 'input'){
            switch (descendents[i].type){
                case 'text':
                case 'password':
                case 'color':
                case 'date':
                case 'email':
                case 'month':
                case 'number':
                case 'range':
                case 'search':
                case 'tel':
                case 'time':
                case 'url':
                case 'week':
                    descendents[i].value = '';
                    break;

                case 'radio':
                case 'checkbox':
                    descendents[i].checked = false;
            }
        }
        else if (descendents[i].tagName.toLowerCase() == 'select'){
            descendents[i].selectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }   
}
```

and to use it:

```
clearFields ('divName');
```

Of course you can add more elements to rest it

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#div_id input[type=textbox], #div_id select, #div_id textarea').val(''); 
$('#div_id input[type=radio], #div_id input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
```

for jquery.