# Clear all textfields inside a DIV with javascript only

Tags: javascript, textfield

I want to clear the contents of all text fields inside a given DIV with a button. I am using this javascript code:

```
<div id="block1">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><!--somefields--></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="button" onclick="clear('block1')" value="clear"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clear(fieldid) {
        document.getElementById(fieldid).childNodes[3].innerHTML='';
    }
</script>
```

but its not working. What is wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by text fields? Inputs?

Comment: Yes, fields where you can input a single line of text.

Comment: Can you share complete piece of code?

Comment: Wrap the whole thing in a form, include a reset button. No script required. Or for unnecessary complexity, call the form's *reset* method.

Comment: its too much code. I already included the most relevant part of it.

Comment: I cant use the reset button because that would reset the whole form and I dont mean that.

Comment: Then wrap them in a fieldset element, loop over the fieldset's *elements* collection doing `fieldset.elements[i].value == fieldset.elements[i].defaultValue`.

Comment: Use `AddEventListener()`....for add click event to each input then use `this.value=""` for clear inputs.

Comment: If you talk about fields in a form you can do : `document.getElementById("nameofthefield").value = '';` to clear the related field.

Comment: Have a look [Simple way to clear the value of any input inside a div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500012/simple-way-to-clear-the-value-of-any-input-inside-a-div)

Comment: can you rename your function to something else other than 'clear' and try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below piece of code working for you with sample input text box

```html
<div id="block1">
     <table>
      <tr>
       <td><input type="text" value="Hello"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td><input type="button" onclick="clearFields('block1')" value="clear"></td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function clearFields(fieldid) {
        var container, inputs, index;

        container = document.getElementById(fieldid);
        inputs = container.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for (index = 0; index < inputs.length; ++index) {
         if(inputs[index].type =="text")
            inputs[index].value = '';
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: This is the right answer. thank you. I just wonder if you can make it even simpler by taking off the loop.

Comment: you can try that customization on your own :)

Comment: The only way I see is by declaring each text field separately, since I have only 4 that would make the code shorter but your solution does the job for all fields no matter how many. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can select all the inputs from needed `div`, and set their values empty in a loop.

```
function clear(fieldid) {
    var container = document.getElementById(fieldid);
    var inputs = container.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var index = 0; index < inputs.length; ++index) {
        inputs[index].value = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it didnt work. Can you make it more simple?

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake.  You should use `value` instead of `val`. My jquery habit. Updated my answer.

Comment: now it works but it clears the values of the button as well hahaha